# What the difference between two double point and one in pseudo-selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am a bit do not understand what is the difference between `:before` and `::before` for example. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is to differentiate between pseudo-classes (such as `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active`) and pseudo-elements (such as `::before`, `::after`, `::first-line`).

This is introduced as part of CSS3, by the World Wide Web Consortium (the W3C), but because pseudo-elements were introduced prior to this syntactic differentiation browsers support both `::before` and `:before`.

According to the reference at the MDN (Mozilla Developer Network):

```
Browser            |  Lowest Version    |    Support of
-------------------+--------------------+------------------
Internet Explorer  |  8.0               |   :pseudo-element
                   +--------------------+------------------
                   | 9.0                |   :pseudo-element
                   |                    |   ::pseudo-element
-------------------+--------------------+------------------
Firefox (Gecko)    | 1.0 (1.0)          |  :pseudo-element
                   +--------------------+------------------
                   | 1.0 (1.5)          |  :pseudo-element
                   |                    |  ::pseudo-element
-------------------+--------------------+------------------
Opera              | 4.0                |  :pseudo-element
                   +--------------------+------------------
                   | 7.0                |  :pseudo-element
                   |                    |  ::pseudo-element
-------------------+--------------------+------------------
Safari (WebKit)    | 1.0 (85)           |  :pseudo-element
                   |                    |  ::pseudo-element
-------------------+--------------------+------------------
```

Note, from the CSS Selectors Recommendation:

> This `::` notation is introduced by the current document in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements.
>   For compatibility with existing style sheets, **user agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced in CSS levels 1 and 2** (namely, `:first-line`, `:first-letter`, `:before` and `:after`).
>   This **compatibility is not allowed for the new pseudo-elements** introduced in this specification.

References:

- [CSS 2.1 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements).
- [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Comment: Can you explain what the difference between them?

Comment: I thought I had; whereabouts are you stuck?

Comment: two double dots, and single. May be any advantages of double?

Comment: There's little 'difference;' user-agents must support the single-colon (the 'double dots' you refer to) for any pseudo-elements introduced prior to CSS 3 (as detailed in the quote I just added to the answer), but must *not* support single-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced under CSS level 3 modules. The only argument for using, for example, `:before`, is to provide compatibility with older browsers, such as IE 8. Whether you wish to support that browser (users of other browsers tend to update regularly) then use single-colon, otherwise don't.

Comment: ok, what is the logic of the creation of the new rules? Why was this necessary? Essentially, I understand your answer, but I would like to detail.

Comment: I can't answer those aspects because, so far as I'm aware, there's no explanation of *why* the syntax was adopted (beyond the need to differentiate between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements). So unless you can contact someone at the W3C that works on the Selectors Module I'm not sure you'll be able to find an answer to that.

Comment: yes, I think I can't:( But anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of some small help! :)

Answer (score 7):

`::before` is the more modern version. Everything starting with `::` is a pseudo-element and everything starting with `:` is a pseudo-class. This distinction has been only made since [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#gen-content).

Use `::before` to use this new standard version *or* use `:before` for backwards-compatibility, as all browsers understand `:before` but not all of them understand `::before`.

Comment: ok, is any table which browser support old and new version of this, or I just should make two version of code? Like `a:before, a::before`?

Comment: @AleshaOleg I’m not sure whether `a:before, a::before` will work in all browsers. Maybe the entire selector will fail as opposed to only the `a::before` part. It’s safer to just use `a:before`.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) has a table with browser support: basically IE8 and lower are the only browsers that you need to worry about. All other browsers that don’t support this are long dead.